# Confused on combining columns

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get specific columns from multiple tables to be put into a single query table dropping columns that do not have active artists and combining the Name column from the two tables. I tried many things with INNER JOIN but I can't figure it out.

For this example lets Name to be combined, NumberOfMembers, Currently active, Songtitle, and how would I drop the columns in relation to the non active artist.

```
create table Artists
( Name text, NumberOfMembers integer, CurrentlyActive text);
create table BestSongsEver
( Name text, SongTitle text, YearCreated integer, Ranking integer, genre text, TimesListenedTo integer, RatingScale integer);


insert into Artists values('Kanye West', 1, 'Yes');
insert into Artists values('Michael Jackson', 1, 'No');
insert into Artists values('Aleyna Tilki', 1, 'Yes');

insert into BestSongsEver values('Kanye West', 'Power', 2010, 1, 'Hip Hop', 237, 9.7);
insert into BestSongsEver values('Aleyna Tilki', 'Cevapsiz Cinlama', 2016, 6, 'Turkish Pop', 70, 8.9);
insert into BestSongsEver values('Michael Jackson', 'Thriller', 1982, 2, 'Pop', 200, 9.2);
```

Query attempt:

```
SELECT *
FROM Artists A
   INNER JOIN BestSongsEver BSE ON BSE.Name = A.Name
```

Comment: Take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp :) Feel also free to add the query you have tryed to use so far

Comment: Learn about SELECT. It is not the right way of thinking to think of SELECT as "dropping columns you don't want", rather "selecting columns you do want".

Comment: Also, can you show what you tried with INNER JOIN and why it didn't work as expected?

Comment: @all SELECT * FROM Artists A INNER JOIN BestSongsEver BSE ON BSE.Name = A.Name ////// Thats what I tried but for some reason it doesn't combine the name columns and I don't know how to drop specific columns and also how to organize the existing columns in the way he wants.

Comment: `select a.name, bse.SongTitle , ...`

Comment: Is it " where currentlyactive != 'no' " that you are missing. That would remove the rows in relation to non active artists. Add it to the end of your query

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean dropping rows without an active artist and not columns.

In this case, you can filter out everything you need with a where clause, this filters your data.

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Artists A
   INNER JOIN BestSongsEver BSE ON BSE.Name = A.Name
   WHERE A.currentlyActive  = 'yes'
```

This will show 'Kanye West' twice as he's in both tables. If you want to filter out columns, you can select the columns you want like this:

```
SELECT A.Name, BSE.Name,...
```